# Does such a semigroup exist?

Tags: logic

A homework question asks if there exists a semigroup that satisfies:

$\forall x\forall y \exists z (x\circ z=y)$, $\forall x\forall y \exists z' (z'\circ x=y)$, $\exists x \exists y\exists z(x\circ z=y \wedge z\circ x \neq y)$

All element has a way to any other element via left or right multiplication, but the left "intermediate" element from x to y is different from the right "intermediate", for some x and y.

Comment: From your other questions and answers, it appears that you have already studied group theory. So why are you posting a question which simply asks if there is a group which contains a pair of noncommuting elements??

Comment: @bof you are right. It is just my thoughts were stuck on the 3rd condition. Didn't realise it suffices to exhibit non commuting elements. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the free group $F$ on two generators $a$ and $b$. Then any element has a (two-sided) inverse, so your first two properties hold (with $z = x^{-1}y$ and $z' = yx^{-1}$). Also, with $x=a$, $y=ab$ and $z=b$, you have $xz = y$ but $zx = ba\neq y$, so your third property holds too.

Comment: How would you prove that the free generators of $F$ don't commute? I would do it by exhibiting some concrete non-Abellian group, and considering the homomorphism which maps the generators of $F$ to a pair of noncommuting elements. So it seems to me that commutativity fails in $F$ **because** there are non-Abelian groups, so it seems circular to use $F$ as your example to demonstrate the existence of non-Abelian groups.

Comment: We have an explicit [construction of free groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group#Construction) that makes it quite clear that the generators don't commute.

Answer (score 1):

Your homework question describes a kind of object called a "non-Abelian group". The smallest example is the set of all permutations of a $3$-element set $X$ (that is, all bijections $f:X\to X$) with the operation of composition. An example that may be familiar to you is the set of all invertible $2\times2$ matrices with the operation of matrix multiplication.